# Modifying Business Card View in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, default-settings

The owner of my company prefers the Outlook Business Card view.  I am tasked with adding the "referred by" field to this view, also making it a searchable field.  I can do it individually, one by one, but is there a way to add this as a default field to the view, or better yet, a default field in all Outlook views?

Comment: Are you trying to do this on a public folder, or users personal folders?  Are you using an Exchange server?

Comment: It's not on an Exchange Server, it is in the users personal folders.

Comment: Ah, with an Exchange server, there are a couple methods to synchronize view settings for public folders.  AFAIK, there is no way to automatically systematically modify anything on a local Outlook client.